# Extracting text inside tags from html document

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags, extract

I have an html document like this: https://dropmefiles.com/wezmb
So I need to extract text inside tags <span id="1" and </span , but I don't know how.
I'm trying and write this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("10_01.htm") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp,features="html.parser")
    for a in soup.find_all('span'):
      print (a.string)
```

But it extract all information from all 'span' tags. So, how can i extract text inside tags <span id="1" and </span in Python?

Comment: You are exclusively using functions from a Python Library named "BeautifulSoup", have you considered just using normal Python functions to parse the text?

Comment: @GeoffGriswald BeautifulSoup has been used to scrape the webpage. It cannot parse text since it is not made for that purpose. Please know the basic libraries corresponding to a topic (I.e. web scraping) before deciding to answer questions in the topic.

Comment: No, I haven't considered using simple features. Could you help with their use to solve this problem?

Comment: @Terry no need to worry about 'normal python functions' since they will not be extracting the text from HTML in an easy way, like `bs4` allows you to (by using the `.find_all` and other methods).

Comment: @Samarth Bhatia oh, okey. Thx for help!

Comment: Samarth you will of course notice that I have not "decided to answer questions in the topic", in fact what I did was post a comment, which is very, very different from an answer. I wasn't suggesting using BeautifulSoup to parse the text, I was suggesting using native Python functions. As it turns out, there is a function in BeautifulSoup to do what the OP wanted, which is great, but I can't possibly know the functionality of every Python Library, and I stand by my original comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the `.contents` function. [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children)

Find the span `<span id = "1"> ... </span>` using

```
for x in soup.find(id = 1).contents:
    print(x)
```

OR

```
x = soup.find(id = 1).contents[0] # since there will only be one element with the id 1.
print(x)
```

This will give you :

```
10
```

that is, an empty line followed by 10 followed by another empty line. This is because the string in the HTML is actually like that and prints 10 in a new line, as you can also see in the HTML that 10 has its separate line.
The string will correctly be `'\n10\n'`.

If you want just `x = '10'` from `x = '\n10\n'` you can do : `x = x[1:-1]` since `'\n'` is a single character. Hope this helped.

Comment: Could you show me what the whole code should look like? Because, replacing only print arguments, it also outputs all the information from all html tags, but in [] and with / n at the beginning and end.  But I only need the text between the two tags `<span id = "1">` and `</span>` which you can see in the html document.

Comment: Oh, okey! I'll wating

Comment: @Terry i've edited my answer to be better

Comment: that's really help so much, but I have 1 simple question: 
Can I use this x argument to insert `10` into the database column?

Comment: What is the database column? (what database is being talked about?)

Comment: about mdb, I need to Insert this value into mdb column

Comment: But aren't we dealing with HTML right now? How can we switch from HTML on our browser to a database, I didn't get that. If you could provide an example of something similar or how you generally insert values into mdb, that would be helpful to answer it further.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, better to make new question. Thank you so much for your answer!
Here is new question link, if u can help  me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606031/insert-text-into-microsoft-access-data-base